# ${status.value} does not work

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I've enabled spring mvc annotation driven in the my project.
After that the spring tags does not work as previously:

```
   <spring:bind path="list">
      <form:select path="mMaxFrequency">
           <form:options items="${status.value}"/>
      </form:select>
   </spring:bind>
```

During rendering a jsp page, I've got the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Type [java.lang.String] is not valid for option items
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String show(@ModelAttribute("form") AccessForm form, Map<String, Object> model) throws IOException {
    AccessSettings settings = getAccessSettings();
    form.setAlertSettings(settings.getAlertSettings());
    form.setMaxFrequency(settings.getMaxFrequency());
    return "page";
}

public class AccessForm{

    public List<Long> getList() {
        // some custom logic that generate long items
    }
}
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Items is plural, `status.value` returns a singular.

Comment: Yes, but could you explain how it related to enabling of annotation driven and why it worked previously?

Comment: @fashuser your jsp is not affected due to annotations you might have mistaken in your controller or service classes .. share them to get a clear answer

Comment: Since it's a String hence you have to use `<form:option value="${status.value}"></form:option>` as per your exception. **I can't it as answer** due to some **Dwonvoter**.

Comment: It crashes with: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20"

Comment: **What the hell is going on StackOverflow today?**

Comment: @Braj what happened dude . Everything seems to work fine

Comment: Guys, I've added my controller with form. Have you any ideas why it have been broken after enabling annotation driven. Please noticed that controller and jsp didn't modified.

Comment: why are you using bind tag instead of just setting `items="${list}"`?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @peter's comment ,

`"${status.value}"` used inside the items attribute returns `String` . while items attribute inside option tag expects `list` . its is very clear from your exception .

Check whether you are adding the items into the `list` in a proper manner. i guess you are overriding the same instance every time

Comment: I've double checked that list return list of long items, namely the following values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20. Could you explain in which place it can be overridden, because the implementation of jsp and controller has not been changed

Comment: Are you sure your jsp is unchanged , i dont find any effort taken to iterate the list

Comment: Yes, jsp is unchanged. But after debuggin I've noticed that my list converts to string through ConversionService. The following service has been null before annotation-driven has been enabled.